# Assign number for instance that loop occured

Tags: pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, multiple-columns

I am trying to assign a number for the instance that the loop gathered the data for each instance, for a later lookup.

The issue that I am having is it will just assign one single number to the column for ALL the looped instances or it just pretty much tells me that it can't and tells me:

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (2)
```

All I want to do is add a number to a column so I know when that instance was pulled through the code.

Please help, I have been banging my head against the wall here.

Thanks y'all

Here is my code:

```
states = ["Washington", "Oregon"]

period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []
i = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()
df[state] = i

for state in states:
    x = state
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    url = driver.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    #dfs  = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
    # Get the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    state_build = url.split('code=',1)[1]
    state_id = state_build[:2]
    table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
    headers = []

    for i in table.find_all('th'):
        title = i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)
    

    
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        length = len(df)

        df = df.append(row_data)
        
        


        dfs = df.set_index(df.groupby(level = 0)\
                  .cumcount(), append = True).stack()\
                  .unstack(0)\
                  .rename(columns={0 : 'COUNTY', 1: 'PRICE', 2: "TOTAL ACRES"})
        
        dfs['STATE'] = i
        time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
    headers = []
    
    i = i + 1

dfs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's precisely what I use `enumerate` for. So going off of QHarr's code (so accept his solution, but I'm just adding to it...), you can see the slight difference (not needing to set `r=0` and then have to increment `r+=1`).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

states = ["Washington", "Oregon"]

period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []
df = pd.DataFrame()

for r, state in enumerate(states): #<- r will be the index position from the list `states` as it iterates through
    x = state
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()#(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    url = driver.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    #dfs  = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
    # Get the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    state_build = url.split('code=',1)[1]
    state_id = state_build[:2]
    table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
    headers = []

    for i in table.find_all('th'): # you use i here!
        title = i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)
    
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        row_data.append(r)  
        length = len(df)      
        df = df.append(row_data)

        dfs = df.set_index(df.groupby(level = 0)\
                  .cumcount(), append = True).stack()\
                  .unstack(0)\
                  .rename(columns={0 : 'COUNTY', 1: 'PRICE', 2: "TOTAL ACRES", 3:"LOOP"})
        time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
    headers = []    
    

dfs
```

**HOWEVER**...any reason you're not using pandas here and just formatting the url?

```
import pandas as pd

states = ["WA", "OR"]
period = "2020"

dfs = []
for state in states:
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm?term=county&state_code={state}&fiscal_yr={period}'.format(state=state,period=period))[-1]
    df['State'] = state
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
               COUNTY      PAYMENT    PAYMENT.1    PAYMENT.2  TOTAL ACRES State
0        ADAMS COUNTY      $59,408      $59,408      $59,408        21337    WA
1       ASOTIN COUNTY     $174,550     $174,550     $174,550        71580    WA
2       BENTON COUNTY     $181,659     $181,659     $181,659        64264    WA
3       CHELAN COUNTY   $3,244,827   $3,244,827   $3,244,827      1486918    WA
4      CLALLAM COUNTY   $1,101,485   $1,101,485   $1,101,485       523298    WA
..                ...          ...          ...          ...          ...   ...
71       WASCO COUNTY      $87,973      $87,973      $87,973       220099    OR
72  WASHINGTON COUNTY      $39,545      $39,545      $39,545        13984    OR
73     WHEELER COUNTY     $120,613     $120,613     $120,613       301762    OR
74     YAMHILL COUNTY      $38,627      $38,627      $38,627        58311    OR
75              TOTAL  $23,321,995  $23,321,995  $23,321,995     31312205    OR
```

Comment: Wow that pandas solution was exactly what I needed...Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable other than i to show the loop increment as i is used within the loop as well. Let's say `r` but appreciate you will need a better name later. Now, you could simply add that to `row_data`, and update the `dfs =`  line to have an extra rename column called `LOOP`.

Note: I think you probably want to revisit the rest of the code and see if there are some simplifications you could make and also replace those hardcoded waits with selenium condition based waits.

```
r = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()

for state in states:
    # ......

    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        row_data.append(r)
        length = len(df)      
        df = df.append(row_data)

        dfs = df.set_index(df.groupby(level = 0)\
                  .cumcount(), append = True).stack()\
                  .unstack(0)\
                  .rename(columns={0 : 'COUNTY', 1: 'PRICE', 2: "TOTAL ACRES", 3:"LOOP"})
        # ..... 
    r+=1
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

states = ["Washington", "Oregon"]

period = "2020"

num_states = len(states)

state_list = []
r = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()

for state in states:
    x = state
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()#(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    url = driver.current_url
    page = requests.get(url)
    #dfs  = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
    # Get the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    state_build = url.split('code=',1)[1]
    state_id = state_build[:2]
    table = soup.findAll('table')[2]
    headers = []

    for i in table.find_all('th'): # you use i here!
        title = i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)
    
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        
        data = row.find_all('td')
        row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
        row_data.append(r)
        length = len(df)      
        df = df.append(row_data)

        dfs = df.set_index(df.groupby(level = 0)\
                  .cumcount(), append = True).stack()\
                  .unstack(0)\
                  .rename(columns={0 : 'COUNTY', 1: 'PRICE', 2: "TOTAL ACRES", 3:"LOOP"})
        time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
    headers = []    
    r+=1

dfs
```